# Why isnt't this code with std::chrono::system_clock working?

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono

I was trying to create a program who tells me what day is tomorrow (starting from 01 Jan) but the code I wrote down doesn't seem to work.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <ratio>
#include <chrono>

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point today = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

std::tm timeinfo = std::tm();
timeinfo.tm_mon = 0;
timeinfo.tm_mday = 1;
std::time_t tt = std::mktime (&timeinfo);

std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t (tt);


std::chrono::duration<int,std::ratio<60*60*24> >one_day (1);


std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tomorrow = today + one_day;


std::time_t tv;

tt = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t ( today );
std::cout << "today is: " << ctime(&tv); 

tt = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t ( tomorrow );
std::cout << "tomorrow will be: " << ctime(&tv);

return 0;
}
```

I'm not getting any error when I compile my code, but when I run my program  the output is:

today is: Thu Jan 01 01:00:34 1970
tomorrow will be: Thu Jan 01 01:00:34 1970

Why is it acting this way?

Thanks everybody!

Comment: Your code does exactly what you should expect it to do. Can you add comments so we can understand why you expect it to do otherwise? Why do you expect a default initialized std::time_t to contain today's date?!

Comment: I wanted my code to set the 'today' variable to 1st of January, that's the only problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `tv` is uninitialized!

See my comments annotating your source code:

```
std::time_t tv; // uninitialized

tt = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(today);
std::cout << "today is: " << ctime(&tv); // did you mean tt?

tt = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(tomorrow);
std::cout << "tomorrow will be: " << ctime(&tv); // did you mean tt?
```

Comment: No, this doesn't solve the problem (see my answer). He uses the wrong variable for storing the result. `tv` being uninitialized is part of the problem, but not the solution.

Comment: @JanWinkler You're right because it wasn't very clear so I added a note telling people to check the comments.

Answer (score 4):

Actually your program is correct. You just messed up the output. The variables used in `ctime` refer to the (non-initialized) variable `tv` instead of the variable `tt` that holds the values you compute from `today` and `tomorrow`.

```
tt = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t ( today );
std::cout << "today is: " << ctime(&tv); 

tt = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t ( tomorrow );
std::cout << "tomorrow will be: " << ctime(&tv);
```

Should be

```
tt = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t ( today );
std::cout << "today is: " << ctime(&tt); 

tt = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t ( tomorrow );
std::cout << "tomorrow will be: " << ctime(&tt);
```

instead. After correcting that, it works for me. I now get this output:

```
today is: Sun Jan 31 13:22:30 2016
tomorrow will be: Mon Feb  1 13:22:30 2016
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, please explain why. This exactly solves OP's problem and explains what went wrong.